# Django book question: Database config problem. Getting Operational Error

Tags: python, database, django

I am on chapter 5 of the django book and trying to proceed, but I'm stuck on one part:

Link to exact chapter: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/

Problem: testing database configurations

When I:

1. Run python manage.py shell form within the mysite project directory
2. Then in the shell type these commands to test database configuration

```
from django.db import connection  
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I get the following error when i do all of the above:

> "OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Was I supposed to create some sort of file within the new directory or folder i created called "MyDB". If so, how do I do this?

Below is how my DB configurations are set:

Configurations:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlite3',             
        'NAME':   'C:/Python27/MyDB',      
        'USER': '',                      
        'PASSWORD': '',                 
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is permissions error.  What are the permissions on the Python27 directory, and do they correspond to the permissions from which you are running the python manage command.

I typically put the database in the project directory, not the python directory.

Comment: fauxtrot, thanks for your response. Do you mean for the administrator? if so my permissions are set allow (checked) for:  full control, modify, read and execute, list folder contents, read, write. The only thing not checked is special permission. What do you mean by "do they correspond to the permissions from which you are running the python manage command". Is there another folder i must check the permissions for? I have put my database directory in my project folder as you have done. Not sure i have to now check the permissions in the project folder as well.

Comment: I basically mean this:  if your python27 directory is admin only rights, you're going to have a hard time creating files (sqlite3 driver) if you are running the command from a non-administrator command window.

Answer (score 0):

You're using sqlite, which creates a database as a file. From what you've said in the question, the value of `NAME` in your database setting is `'C:/Python27/MyDB'`, which points to a *directory*. Set that value to `'C:/Python27/MyDB/mydb.db'` or something similar. You don't need to actually create the file, Django will do that for you when you run `manage.py syncdb`.